# Can someone explain what this JS snippet is doing?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me what this snippet is doing?

Is it setting x to true if y is undefined?

```
var x = false;
var y = x === true;
```

Comment: It's assigning the result of `x === true`, i.e. `false === true`, to `y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```js
 var x = false;
 var y = x === true;
 console.log(y);
```

is simply checking the condition `x === true`, like other programming language it will result to either `true` or `false`. Since you have `var x = false;` the condition `x === true` will result in `false` as `false === true` is always false. Now, the result of this condition is being assigned to the new variable `y` as `var y = x === true;` so the value for y will be `false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `x` to `false`
2. Is `x` *exactly-equal* to `true`?

   2.1. If so, then set `y` to `true`

   2.2. Otherwise, set `y` to `false`

There is no invokation of of `global.undefined` in this fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be pretty clear, it sets `x` to `false`. The second line is a bit more difficult, first, it compares `x` to `true`. If `x` is exactly equal to `true`, it will set `y` to true. Since `x` is `false`, the comparison will also return `false`, so `y` will be set to `false`.

TL;DR, this is a convoluted way of setting `y` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`===` is a [strict comparison operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/6638533). The value of variable `y` will only `true` if `x` is **boolean** and **true**, `y` will be `false` otherwise. Check this snippet out for example:

```js
let a = 1;
console.log(a == true); // print true

let b = 1;
console.log(b === true); // print false, because `b` is a number, not boolean

let c = true;
console.log(c == true); // print true

let d = true;
console.log(d === true); // print true, because `d` is a boolean and its value is `true`
```

This `var y = x === true;` statement means: keep the returned value of `(x === true)` in the `y` variable. In your case, `y` will hold `false` as its value since `x` is a **boolean**, but its value is **false**.

Answer (score -2):

Strict Equality Operator, `===` has a greater precedence over Assignment Operator, `=`. Therefore the check for `x` is done before assigning its value to `y`.

You can break this down into three statements.

```
var x = false
var tmp = (x === true)
var y = tmp
```

Since `x` is `false`, `y` will also get set to `false`.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything, you just complicated things further